# page template - undefined structure in source code

Tags: pages, page-template, debug

hey,
i have the following page template for a sitemap.

```
<?php
/**
 * Template Name: Sitemap
 */
?>
<?php if (have_posts()) : while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>

    <div>
        <h3>Pages</h3>
            <ul>
                <?php wp_list_pages('title_li=&depth=0&exclude='); ?>
            </ul>
        <h3>Posts</h3>
            <?php $first = 0;?>
            <ul>
            <?php
            $myposts = get_posts('numberposts=-1&offset=$first');
            foreach($myposts as $post) :
            ?>
            <li><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>#b"><?php the_title(); ?></a></li>
            <?php endforeach; ?>
            </ul>
        <h3>Categories</h3>
            <ul>
                <?php wp_list_categories('title_li=&orderby=name'); ?>
            </ul>
        <h3>Tags</h3>
            <ul>    
                <?php
                $tags = get_tags();
                foreach ($tags as $tag){
                    $tag_link = get_tag_link($tag->term_id);
                    $html .= "<li><a href='{$tag_link}#b' title='{$tag->name} Tag' class='{$tag->slug}'>";
                    $html .= "{$tag->name}</a></li>";
                }
                echo $html;
                ?>
            </ul>
    </div>

<?php endwhile; endif; ?>
```

It's my intention to not define a header with  or  or anything like that, because this thing is only used to get loaded via an ajax call.

However the output of this thing looks like this

```
<div> 
    <h3>Pages</h3> 
    <ul> 
        <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40/loose.dtd"> 
        <html><body> 
            <li class="page_item page-item-87"><a href="http://domain.com/account#b" title="Account">Account</a></li> 
            <li class="page_item page-item-67"><a href="http://domain.com/forum-3#b" title="Forum">Forum</a></li> 
            <li class="page_item page-item-107"><a href="http://domain.com/map#b" title="Google Map">Google Map</a></li> 
            <li class="page_item page-item-79"><a href="http://domain.com/contact#b" title="ContaCt">Contact</a></li> 
            <li class="page_item page-item-92"><a href="http://domain.com/login#b" title="Login">Login</a></li> 
            <li class="page_item page-item-93"><a href="http://domain.com/register#b" title="Register">Register</a></li> 
        </body></html> 
    </ul> 
    <h3>Posts</h3> 
    <ul> 
        <li><a href="http://domain.com/test-post#b">Test post</a></li> 
        <li><a href="http://domain.com/lorem-ipsum-test-page#b">Lorem Ipsum Test Page</a></li> 
        <li><a href="http://domain.com/hello-world#b">Hello</a></li> 
    </ul> 
    <h3>Categories</h3> 
    <ul> 
        <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40/loose.dtd"> 
        <html><body><li class="cat-item cat-item-1"> 
            <a href="http://domain.com/category/something#b" title="Show all posts">Something</a> 
        </li></body></html> 
    </ul> 
</div>
```

Any idea why there is a weird doctype declaration and a `<html><body>` inserted inside of every `ul`. Except for the Posts `ul`. Just weird. Why could that happen and what causes this? I actually use a html5 doctype on my website.

Thank you for the help

edit:

```
add_filter('wp_list_pages', 'add_hash'); /*Add #hash to wp_list_pages() function*/
add_filter('wp_list_categories', 'add_hash'); /*Add #hash to wp_list_categories() function*/
function add_hash($output) {

        $dom = new DOMDocument();
        $dom->loadHTML($output);

        $a_tags = $dom->getElementsByTagName('a');

        foreach($a_tags as $a)
        {
            $value = $a->getAttribute('href');
            $a->setAttribute('href', $value . '#b');
        }

        return $dom->saveHTML();
}
```

The new DOMDocument is adding this doctype declaration and the  and

Comment: Is this the real source code or just the DOM created by the browser?

Comment: this is the real source when I look it up in the browser (browser view source - not just a dom inspector) ... all browsers print the same source code.

Comment: what do you mean by real source though? How can i look up a real source code...the real source code is the sitemap.php file...and the source that's generated is the one i posted above.

Comment: Yes, I meant the source view in the browser. Your output looks like it comes from a different template: the trailing `#b` is missing and the entire tag list too.

Comment: oh sorry, i got rid of the trailing #b so it doesn't look confusing - ( bad idea :) )... no it's the same template - i just wanted to simplify the output for this question here so it doesn't look confusing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Search all your theme and plugin files for:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.0 Transitional//EN"
```

Disable all plugins and re-enable them step by step. This document type declaration is not part of WordPress’ core files; there is a filter active somewhere.

#### Update

Try to remove all filters from the affected functions. Start with wp_list_pages():

```
remove_all_filters( 'wp_list_pages_excludes', 99 );
remove_all_filters( 'wp_list_pages', 99 );
```

I still don’t believe that the doctype is nowhere to be found. That is impossible.

Comment: good point. However not even a single file contains this declaration. Any other ideas - this behaviour is just strange. can I try to remove filters on this page?

Comment: @mathiregister I have added some code to disable the filters. It would really help if could just point us to the URI of the document.

Comment: i got it! remove_all_filters works fine, thank you. However the problem is not a plugin is adding this doctype declaration but I am doing it. I'm using the DOMDocument class to add a #b hash to each page-link and category-link. I updated my question. maybe you have an idea how I could prevent my filter from doing that?

Comment: There is a filter for `'post_link'` in `get_permalink()`. You could add your own filter at the start of your template and insert the string without any DOM manipulation or regex.

Answer (score 1):

The DOMDocument approach seems like an overly complicated one for what you're trying to do. Couldn't you just do this with a regex filter?

```
add_filter('wp_list_pages', 'add_hash'); 
add_filter('wp_list_categories', 'add_hash'); 

function add_hash($output) {
    return preg_replace( 
        '/<a\s(.*?)href="(.*?)"(.*?)>/', 
        '<a $1href="$2#b"$3>', $output );
}
```

(written quickly, apologies if this regex doesn't catch everything... its just for the concept though...)

Answer (score 0):

How are you loading this template? Is it being included *within* another template file that already calls get_header() and get_footer(), or is your AJAX call creating a new window (i.e. a new document)?

Also: why are you putting your content inside of a Loop? For one, you never output the_content() or the_excerpt(); for another thing, I assume that, for a Sitemap, you don't *intend* to add any Page content, but rather merely assign the template to a given Page?

Comment: it's going to be included inside of a nother page the already has get_header() and get_footer() included (like you said)... i didn't know i could get rid of the loop - now i got rid of it. however that doesn't change anything to the fact that there is this doctype inserted.